# How to show invoice no and date in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, invoice

I am using a page to display order details and want to show invoice no and date in that page. Please tell me how to show invoice no. Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 invoice-`co`l">
    <b>Order No. </b>#
    <?php if ($this->getNoUseOrderLink()): ?>
        <?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId(); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br>
    <b>Amount:</b> <?php echo "&nbsp".$this->gettotalamount(); ?><br>
    <b>Payment Type:</b> <?php echo $_order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); ?>
```

Comment: please edit your question. your code is not visible

Comment: code is edited now check

Comment: help me please provide me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code snippet to get Invoice info associated with any order. Based on your code, you have already loaded order model on `$_order`, so try below code.

```
<?php
// ignore below two lines if you already have order model
// $_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($anyorderincrementid);
// $_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($anyorderentityid);

if ($_order->hasInvoices()) {
     $invIncrementIDs = array();
     foreach ($_order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
                echo "Invoice Id- ".$inv->getIncrementId();
                echo "Invoice Date- ".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($inv->getCreatedAt()));
     }
}
?>
```

To get date in d-m-y format (answer of your question which is in comments)

```
<?php 
// format admin and store date
$orderAdminDate=date('d-m-y',strtotime($orderAdminDate));
$orderStoreDate=date('d-m-y',strtotime($orderStoreDate));

echo $orderAdminDate;
if ($orderAdminDate != $orderStoreDate):
    echo date('d-m-y',strtotime($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()));
    echo $orderStoreDate; 
endif;
?>
```

Comment: there is any way to show order no without entring particular order id. it will auto load the invoice no. by fetching the order id automatically. which order id is using at the above.

Comment: means i dont want to add order no. i want to load order no automatically and it will show ivoice no and in invoice date i want to show only date not time. and want to show invoice no. like this not in array and not in any bracket. want to show order date only not time and order date format will be d/m/y thanks in advance. beacuse i am using it to create retail invoice want to load order no automatically in this code.

Comment: Updated my answer. Plz check.

Comment: I think you are missing php tags, that's why all code is coming up as html.

Comment: i am getting this error Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /home/s250

Comment: Iooks it's because of this line $_order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() within your code (from the above you have given in question). Try to get payment data using $orderObj->getPayment()->getData(); It will give all info, first print_r that and take the element data which you want.

Comment: please edit the code i am confused with invoice no and date code

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. The error you said (Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object) is because of a set of code you have included within your question. The answer which I have posted doesn't consist of any function getMethodInstance(). So please fix that. And the answer should give the correct invoice and date.

Comment: i have removed the code for showing payment type but invoice no and date not showing

Comment: Can you share your exact code, what you are trying..?

Comment: thanks you very much now all thing working fine and also payment method working. i want to also know one thing i am using a code to show order date its showing time also i want to show only date and which format will be in d-m-y here is the code <?php echo $orderAdminDate ?>
                    <?php if ($orderAdminDate != $orderStoreDate):?>
                    <?php echo $_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(); ?>
                    <?php echo $orderStoreDate ?>
                    <?php endif;?>

Comment: You can format the date using php date function as date('d-m-y',strtotime($youvariablewhichhasdate));

Comment: plese tell me the code i am beginer so.. thanks in advance

Comment: Updated my answer. Plz check.